# For a newlywed couple, is a distanced relationship grounds for divorce?

Tags: nikah, talaq, relationships

Suppose we have a newlywed couple who have known each other a short time, but with limited conversations about beliefs/future etc.  What if the couple do not get along such as that there is a "distance" between the two?

It's not anybody's fault, but what if they just don't have any other common ground or for them to engage in many conversations? Furthermore, their work schedule is terrible in that one spouse works during the day, while the other works during the night, so they rarely have time to spent together. During the hour or two that they do see each other, there is hardly anything to talk about; no closeness, no conversation of any kind besides customaries.

Is it possible to have a talaq in this case?

I am sure you cannot imagine someone living or being married in this situation where there is no compatibility or anything; what kind of life would one lead?

I know Allah SWT hates divorces but in this situation, there are compatibility issues.  Is it deemed "reasonable" grounds for divorce and separate with the mutual love and respect for each other without any ill-will?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for answering questions or arguing tangential points.